# Inline if-else runs twice in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a problem when trying to go to different pages, the inline if-else runs twice 1 time for if and 1 time for else, for example: I added a log to the dashboard route and when "isAuthenticated" is true i get redirected to /dashboard but i also get the console log at the same time(if i have Navigate instead of log i get redirected twice that is the problem i am trying to fix) any idea why this is happening ?

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import './App.css';
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Navigate} from "react-router-dom";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

//components
import Login from "./components/Login";
import Register from "./components/Register";
import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Auction from "./components/Auction";
//import Home from "./components/Home";


function App() {
  const checkAuthenticated = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/auth/is-verify", {
        method: "GET",
        headers: { token: localStorage.token }
      
      });

      const parseRes = await res.json();

      parseRes === true ? setIsAuthenticated(true) : setIsAuthenticated(false);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    checkAuthenticated();
  }, []);

  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  const setAuth = boolean => {
    setIsAuthenticated(boolean);
  };
  
//<Route path = '/auth' element = {<Auth/>} />
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Router>
        <div className="container">
          <Routes>
          <Route path='/home' element = {
                isAuthenticated ? (
                  <Home setAuth={setAuth}  />
                ) : (
                  <Navigate to="/login" />
                )
              } />
            <Route path='/login' element = {
                !isAuthenticated ? (
                  <Login setAuth={setAuth}  />
                ) : (
                  <Navigate to="/home" />
                )
              } />
            <Route path='/register' element = {
                !isAuthenticated ? (
                  <Register setAuth={setAuth}  />
                ) : (
                  <Navigate to="/home" />
                )
              } />
           **<Route path='/dashboard' element = {
                isAuthenticated ? (
                  <Dashboard setAuth={setAuth}  />
                ) : (
                  console.log("dashboard")
                )
              } />**
              
              <Route path='/auction' element = {
               
                  <Auction setAuth={setAuth}  />
              
        
              } />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: When you `setIsAuthenticated` you are updating the react state and therefore it rerenders. Any time state or props change it will rerender. Your console log is inside of the render so you call it once in the initial render where isAuthenticated is false. Then you checkAuthentication, set it to true and render again.

Comment: Thanks, any idea what should i do to prevent that from  happening  ?

Comment: Are you rendering your app into a `React.StrictMode` component? Are you running React 18? If so, this is pretty much expected behavior in the non-production builds. See [Ensuring Reusable State](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#ensuring-reusable-state).

Comment: @Dimo It depends on what you are trying to solve. You will need to provide some additional information on what is happening that you don't want to happen (or what isn't happening that you do want to happen).
There isn't really anything wrong as far as I can see, this is the expected behaviour.